# Short story about an alien bomb

Tags: story-identification

I've been trying to find out the name of a short story, any help will be appreciated:

- Setting (I think) was World War II
- There was a gunboat in the latter part of the story
- The bomb is sentient, and can move around - it also looks like a rock.
- The bomb cannot see water, so it looks like boats are flying.
- It scans boats using radiation, trying to learn about them - which kills a bunch of the crew.
- In turn they fire on the 'rock' - which prompts it to remember its purpose.
- The story ends with the bomb saying something like "**ah yes, that's what I was supposed to do**" and detonating.

The story turns up in a bunch of anthologies, I just don't have them anymore to check - and google results are swamped by the World War II references.

Many thanks.

Comment: There is a very similar part in John Carpenter's [*Dark Star*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_Star_(film)).

Comment: Anyone else has to think of a bomb with GLaDOS' voice and personality? In the shape of a rocky potato? :)

Comment: @Mario Actually, I remember the story and the bomb isn't malevolent -- just amnesiac and curious. It doesn't even notice the humans it's killing because it was deployed against a silicon-based species that was wiped out in a mutually destructive war millions of years before and organic life didn't exist yet.

Answer (score 22):

The story is "[Dormant](http://www.prosperosisle.org/spip.php?article267)" by A. E. Van Vogt.

> This dramatic tale of the harrowing results of the discovery of a huge and very strange alien object on a remote Pacific island in the immediate post-WW2 years, told in typical and most effective van-Vogt-style from the “other’s” point of view, was first published in the November 1948 issue of *Startling Stories*, whose snappy cover here has surely not escaped your attention.

I found it in a collection called *[Destination Universe](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1640223.Destination)*.

An excerpt from the story:

> As the plant drew closer he sent cautious thoughts towards it. Several planes, to which he had directed his thought waves, had twisted jerkily in mid-air and tumbled down out of control.
>   This one did not deviate from its course. When it was almost directly overhead a large object dropped from it, turned lazily over and over as it curved towards Iilah. It was set to explode about a hundred feet above the target.
>   The timing was perfect, the explosion titanic.
>   As soon as the blurring effects of so much new energy had passed, the now fully alive Iilah thought in a quiet though rather startled comprehension, "Why, of course, that’s what I was trying to remember. That’s what I was supposed to do."

Comment: Fantastic, that's exactly what I was looking for - it was just... Dormant... In my memory. Thanks!

Comment: :-) I've spent all day searching my bookshelf for that flipping story!

Comment: Quite right -- I remember the story vividly, but I couldn't place the author and title.

Answer (score 1):

From the Wikipedia page for [Dark Star](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_Star_(film)), well known for featuring a plotline with "smart bombs" that prematurely decide to explode:

> Commentators have noted that the film's ending closely parallels the short story "Kaleidoscope" by Ray Bradbury, from his 1951 short story collection The Illustrated Man.

Comment: I'm sure the story is neither Dark Star nor Kaleidoscope. I have read the story in the past but I can't remember the title or author. As I recall the bomb is left over from an alien war and is millions (billions?) of years old. It is woken by radioactive fallout from the tests at Bikini atoll. I remember that the bomb can't perceive water and is puzzled about the boats apparently flying.