# Short story with opening phrase "Old was the island."

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Many years ago I read a Sci-Fi story with the opening words "Old was the island" and I'm hoping someone can help track it down.

**- Author:** Unknown. I want to say Asimov, but that's just a guess, and probably wrong.

**- Date:** 1950s or maybe 60s, from my vague recollection of the style.

**- Summary:** A remote island, which is really an alien robot warship that crashed on Earth long, long ago. It has survived on minimal atomic power, almost but not quite dead. It somehow wakes up, but I forget how and what the consequences were.

**- Other Notes:** Somewhat similar to a *Berserker* short story the name of which I also can't recall, but the one I'm looking for is definitely not by Saberhagen. Another possibly incorrect recollection: the warship may have been woken up by a nearby nuclear explosion (test?) from which it captured radiation energy.

Comment: For future reference there's a [confirmation comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/31330/short-story-about-an-alien-bomb#comment59146_31341) on the duplicate target by a deleted user which does appear to be the OP. The duplicate closure here is fine.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is a short story by Van Vogt, "Dormant", about a robotic being called Iilah, left (fallen?) and forgotten near an island in the South Pacific. In some versions, the story begins, "Old was **that** island":

> OLD was that island. Even the thing that lay in the outer channel
> exposed to the rude wash of the open sea had never guessed, when it was alive a million years before, that here was a protuberance of
> primeval earth itself. The island was roughly three miles long and, at its widest, half a mile across. It curved tensely around a blue lagoon and the thin shape of its rocky, foam-ridden arms and hands came down
> toward the toe of the island—like a gigantic man bending over,
> striving to reach his feet and not quite making it.
>
> Through the
> channel made by that gap between the toes and the fingers came the
> sea. The water resented the channel. With an endless patience it
> fought to break the wall of rock and the tumult of the waters was a
> special sound, a blend of all that was raucous and unseemly in the
> eternal quarrel between resisting land and encroaching wave.
>
> At the very hub of the screaming waters lay Iilah, dead now almost forever, forgotten by time and the universe.

You can find it [here](https://www.prosperosisle.org/spip.php?article267).

Comment: Ah very well done, beat me to it! How did you find it? I found it through a Google books search for "Old was the island", and it was one of the first results.

Comment: @fez Ahh, I never thought of checking Google books.

Comment: @LSerni Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. It's entirely likely that the version I read did start with "Old was that island", and I misremembered it over the years.

Comment: @fez believe it or not, I had read that story (albeit in Italian) and the beginning haunted me too. But I also remembered the *name* of the construct, so the Google search landed on it first thing. I thought the OP would have already run the search, so I did not even try that, because I expected the wording to be slightly off (it happens to me all the time, because the first books I read were in Italian, and the translators at the time were famously, eh, *quite creative*).

Comment: Possibly a duplicate if the "Thanks" comment to John Rennie's answer to this old question is from the original poster. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/31330/short-story-about-an-alien-bomb