# Short science fiction story about a sentient atomic bomb named Iglatha

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The bomb (or more accurately a mine) named Iglatha was left on Earth by an ancient civilization. It was long dormant, but awakened in 1945 following the atomic bomb tests. Further misguided actions caused the bomb to explode, causing destruction of humanity.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, did you read it in an anthology, a magazine, or online?

Comment: Hi.  Welcome to SciFi.SE!  Please note -- the best way to thank an answerer (and help future people looking at the question is to mark the answer accepted with the checkmark under the vote count).   Please also note that this question may be closed as a duplicate -- this in no way indicates that it was not a good question; it it site bookkeeping that helps others later.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is almost certainly [Dormant](http://www.prosperosisle.org/spip.php?article267) by A. E. van Vogt, as discussed in [Short story about an alien bomb](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/31330/short-story-about-an-alien-bomb). However the bomb is called *Iilah* not *Iglatha*.

Comment: Yes that is it. Thank you, thank you very much.